# get time back to 12 not 0

Tags: javascript, time

i have an if statement to change time back to 12 after it hits 11:45:

```
        i = (i >= 192) ? i - 192 : ( i >= 96) ? i - 96 : i
        var mins = (i * 15 % 60)
        var hours = Math.floor(i * 15 / 60)
        var ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM"


        hours = (hours == 0) ? 12 : (hours >= 12) ? hours - 12 : hours;


        var nextMins, nextHours = hours;
        switch (mins) {
            case 0:
                mins = "";
                nextMins = 15;
                break;
            case 45:
                nextMins = "";
                nextHours = hours+1;
                break;
            default:
                nextMins = mins + 15;
                break;

        }

        var time = hours + (mins == "" ? "" : ":" + mins) + " - " + nextHours + (nextMins == "" ? "" : ":" + nextMins) + ampm
```

it changes in 15 minute intervals, the issue is it will start at 12 but after it gets to 12:00 again it will display as 0:15, 0:30, 0:45.  Instead of 12:15, 12:30, 12:45

I thought this part of the if statement would do it:

```
hours = (hours == 0) ? 12
```

but isn't working?

Comment: Can you put this up on jsFiddle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way is probably

```
hours = (hours % 12) || 12;
```

This way copes with any positive integer for hours (eg. 36 will still return 12).

Comment: this works well, but realized i need to address when its 12:45, not to show 12:45 - 13PM in my switch, can you do an if statement in a switch statement to pick up on that?

Comment: +1. Nice alternative. @Xtian: you can put an `if` inside your `case`, or use a variation on Dave's code: `nextHours = (hours+1) % 12 || 12;`

Comment: btw. You can replace the first line of your code completely with `i %= 96;`

Answer (score 3):

It should read

```
hours = (hours == 0) ? 12 : (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours;
```

By having >= you're currently including 12 as a number to deduct 12 from.

Answer (score 1):

```
hours = (hours == 0) ? 12 : hours;
```

is the complete usage of ternary conditional. But why don't you use a simple if statement?

```
if(hours == 0)
  hours = 12;
```

Comment: "is the correct usage of ternary conditional" --- so? And why OP's usage is incorrect? From which point of view your one is "more correct" (as long as it does **another work**)?

Comment: The code in the question is completely correct use of the ternary conditional, it's just the actual condition tested isn't quite right (see cchana's answer).